# validate email format only if not blank Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want to validate the email only if the email has been entered.

I tried the following:

```
validates :email, :presence => {:message => "Your email is used to save your greeting."},
                  :email => true,
                  :if => Proc.new {|c| not c.email.blank?},
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

However this does not work as it stops error messages from showing when the  email is left blank.

How can I validate the presence of the email when it is missing and ONLY validate the format when it has been entered?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
validates :email,:presence => {:message => "Your email is used to save your greeting."}, :allow_blank => true,:uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Use`:allow_blank => true` or `:allow_nil => true, :if => :email?`

edit: fix typo.

Comment: HI Avaya, I added :email => true so that it runs the format validation but other than that I took it as written. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I Just used:
    validates :email,:presence => {}, :allow_nil => true

Answer (score 7):

You can write custom validation function:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_email

  protected
  def check_email
    if email.blank?
      validates :email, :presence => {:message => "Your email is used to save your greeting."}
    else
      validates :email,
        :email => true,
        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }      
    end
  end
end
```

or divide your validator into 2 separate validators with conditions:

```
validates :email, 
  :presence => {:message => "Your email is used to save your greeting."}, 
  :if => Proc.new {|c| c.email.blank?}

validates :email, 
  :email => true,
  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  :unless => Proc.new {|c| c.email.blank?}
```

Comment: THanks Hck.  I used your ideas in my answer. I appreciate you getting back to me so quickly. I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: Your first version throws "undefined method `validates' for #<Model>"

Answer (score 1):

you can validate format if no precense required
:allow_nil => true