# Rails validation on certain attribute on a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking into using the same controller for a different page for contacts. However the new page needs phone as well.

So right now the Contact Model has the following for validation:

```
validates :name, email, :interest, presence: true
```

No issues. The new page will use a default interest that I'll set. I do want to require phone ONLY on a certain page though. Besides doing UI validation on presence I'd like to actually validate in the model.

So is there a clean way to validate a single attribute on the model that looks at the point of origin (ie page)?

Comment: If you're only skipping validation on a certain page (i.e. controller), I'd redefine the save method in there to Contact.save(validate: false). Much easier than writing out lengthy conditionals in the method in my opinion.

Comment: Your other options are summed up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661413/rails-3-how-to-skip-validation-rule/48220011#48220011

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `:on` option (or validation contexts). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

You can do something like:

```
validates :phone, presence: true, on: :some_conext
```

Then on the action that updates the attribute

```
if user.save(context: :some_context)
  ....
```